# type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Source

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, audio

I have url of music stored in the firestore. Below in the code I am trying to play audio as per the url but I am unable to play the audio and I am getting Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Source'. I am using audiplayers package.

```
 Row (
          mainAxisAlignment:  MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Text(formatTime(position)),
            Text(formatTime(duration-position)),
            CircleAvatar(
              radius: 35,
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(isPlaying ? Icons.pause: Icons.play_arrow_rounded), onPressed: () async{
                    if (isPlaying){
                      await audioPlayer.pause();
                    } else {

                 await audioPlayer.play(widget.music);
                    }

                },
                ),
            )
          ],

    )
```

Comment: Try to convert position to string like this - > Text(formatTime(position.toString()))

Comment: doesnot work out. same issue.

Comment: In which line error is displaying?

Comment: await audioPlayer.play(widget.music);

Comment: In this line mainly the error is that, you are providing a source in the ->await audioPlayer.play(widget.music);  but its needed to pass a string instead of ->widget.music.    OR try widget.music.toString()

Comment: Thank you so much for the effort on helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[play](https://pub.dev/documentation/audioplayers/latest/audioplayers/AudioPlayer/play.html) method requires [Source](https://pub.dev/documentation/audioplayers/latest/audioplayers/Source-class.html) class as a parameter. E.g. with a remote url:

```
await audioPlayer.play(UrlSource(widget.music));
```